# Twilio channel already exists

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

How can I fix this porblem:

> Channel with provided unique name already exists

Here is the code for creating channel:

```
 tc.joinGeneralChannel = function () {
console.log('Attempting to join ' + $channelName + 'chat channel...');
if (!tc.generalChannel) {

  console.log('Channel doesn\'t exists');
  // If it doesn't exist, let's create it
  tc.messagingClient.createChannel({
    uniqueName: $channelName,
    friendlyName: $channelName
  }).then(function (channel) {
    tc.generalChannel = channel;
    tc.loadChannelList(tc.joinGeneralChannel);
  });
} else {
  setupChannel(tc.generalChannel);
}
```

};

The behavior is weird because the issue is not consistent.

Most of my code are the same with the tutorial twilio provided for laravel framework [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-php-laravel#join-other-channels)

Is there a way to check if the unique name is already exists and then just join in there?

Comment: Facing the same issue, came here for help :)